# How to send test results and code coverage results to SonarQube project after executing analysis

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I have a monolith and I would like to execute both static code analysis and code coverage reporting to sonar. However, my sonar scanning takes at least 30 mins and it is very bad for the CI feedback time.

I was wondering if there is a way to run static code analysis in parallel to different tasks and report test coverage to sonar in the later stage of the CI. I need them in a single scan.

The SQ document is clear about the nonavailability of parallel scanning. but, this isn't parallel but just aggregation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. SonarScanner sends all data together. It also requires access to the test results to present data correctly. You may consider splitting test executions to safe some time.

```
                  /-> test 1/3 --\
                 /                \
Start --> Build ----> test 2/3 -----> SonarScanner --> End
                 \                /
                  \-> test 3/3 --/
```

Comment: I do have tests in parallel with 20 parallel runs. Dividing them further isn't possible due to design limitations.  I am ready to send data in one go to sonarqube server, provided I execute static code scanner beforehand along with other stages such as build or test.

Comment: As I wrote, it is impossible to do it in two steps.